# Mostrar Difenrentes Div com Foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma pagina Inicial que lista Projetos, cada div tem um class diferente da outra, por exemplo, o primeiro projeto, mostra uma imagem, que está em uma div que tem uma class `col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12`, já os dois proximos estão em uma div com a class `col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12`. Então, quando eu vou listar os projetos na pagina inicial, eu uso um:

```html
Foreach(var Item in Projetos)
{
<div class="project-block masonry-item col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <!-- Overlay Box -->
                        <div class="overlay-box">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h6><a href="projeto.html">Nome Do Projeto</a></h6>
                                        <div class="category">Categoria</div>
                                        <a class="plus" href="images/gallery/1.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption=""><span class="flaticon-plus-symbol"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
}
```

Ou seja, assim eu vou repetir sempre a mesma div, com a mesma class.
Ja pesquisei bastante, e vi que provalvelmente só vou conseguie resolver isso com um JavaScrip e/ou Jquery. porém eu não tenho uma base sólida, de como fazer isso.
Esse aqui é o layout que eu to tentando montar na pagina Inicial
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui é o HTML da pagina Principal, "Da parte onde mostra os projetos"

```
<section class="gallery-section">
    <div class="auto-container">
        <!-- Title Box -->
        <div class="title-box">
            <h1>Olá. Aqui vamos ver alguns trabalhos <br> de graffite no estado de Rondônia</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="styled-border">
        </div>
        <div class="masonry-items-container row clearfix">

            <!-- Project Block -->
            <div class="project-block masonry-item col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <!-- Overlay Box -->
                        <div class="overlay-box">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h6><a href="projeto.html">Nome Do Projeto</a></h6>
                                        <div class="category">Categoria</div>
                                        <a class="plus" href="images/gallery/1.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption=""><span class="flaticon-plus-symbol"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Project Block -->
            <div class="project-block masonry-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/gallery/2.jpg" alt="" />
                        <!-- Overlay Box -->
                        <div class="overlay-box">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h6><a href="projeto.html">Nome Do Projeto</a></h6>
                                        <div class="category">Categoria</div>
                                        <a class="plus" href="images/gallery/2.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption=""><span class="flaticon-plus-symbol"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Project Block -->
            <div class="project-block masonry-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/gallery/3.jpg" alt="" />
                        <!-- Overlay Box -->
                        <div class="overlay-box">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h6><a href="projeto.html">Nome Do Projeto</a></h6>
                                        <div class="category">Categoria</div>
                                        <a class="plus" href="images/gallery/3.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption=""><span class="flaticon-plus-symbol"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Project Block -->
            <div class="project-block masonry-item col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/gallery/4.jpg" alt="" />
                        <!-- Overlay Box -->
                        <div class="overlay-box">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h6><a href="projeto.html">Nome Do Projeto</a></h6>
                                        <div class="category">Categoria</div>
                                        <a class="plus" href="images/gallery/4.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption=""><span class="flaticon-plus-symbol"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Project Block -->
            <div class="project-block masonry-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/gallery/5.jpg" alt="" />
                        <!-- Overlay Box -->
                        <div class="overlay-box">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h6><a href="projeto.html">Nome Do Projeto</a></h6>
                                        <div class="category">Categoria</div>
                                        <a class="plus" href="images/gallery/5.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption=""><span class="flaticon-plus-symbol"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Project Block -->
            <div class="project-block masonry-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/gallery/6.jpg" alt="" />
                        <!-- Overlay Box -->
                        <div class="overlay-box">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h6><a href="projeto.html">Nome Do Projeto</a></h6>
                                        <div class="category">Categoria</div>
                                        <a class="plus" href="images/gallery/6.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption=""><span class="flaticon-plus-symbol"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Project Block -->
            <div class="project-block masonry-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/gallery/7.jpg" alt="" />
                        <!-- Overlay Box -->
                        <div class="overlay-box">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h6><a href="projeto.html">Nome Do Projeto</a></h6>
                                        <div class="category">Categoria</div>
                                        <a class="plus" href="images/gallery/7.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption=""><span class="flaticon-plus-symbol"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Project Block -->
            <div class="project-block masonry-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/gallery/8.jpg" alt="" />
                        <!-- Overlay Box -->
                        <div class="overlay-box">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h6><a href="projeto.html">Nome Do Projeto</a></h6>
                                        <div class="category">Categoria</div>
                                        <a class="plus" href="images/gallery/8.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption=""><span class="flaticon-plus-symbol"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Project Block -->
            <div class="project-block masonry-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="inner-box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/gallery/9.jpg" alt="" />
                        <!-- Overlay Box -->
                        <div class="overlay-box">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h6><a href="projeto.html">Nome Do Projeto</a></h6>
                                        <div class="category">Categoria</div>
                                        <a class="plus" href="images/gallery/9.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption=""><span class="flaticon-plus-symbol"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Lower Content -->
        @Html.Action("_FrasePagina", "Home")

    </div>
</section>
```

Alguém sabe me falar como eu consigo montar esse layout. ja que meu loop só pode ser feito em um bloco de divs, como eu usaria um script para solucionar esse problema? é possivel fazer usando apenas propriedades do Asp.Net MCV?

Comment: Não entendi direito, vc tem essa primeira div maior, e quer que sempre que incluir um novo item ele seja o maior, e o maior que já estava lá "ande" para o lado e fique menor, tipo indo para o lugar do segundo filho que estava lá é isso?

Comment: Na verdade cada bloco com essa marcação `<!-- Project Block -->`, é uma div com class diferente, então quando eu vou fazer um loop, geralmente só da pra repetir um unico bloco. como eu quero montar esse layour que eu postei a foto, eu queria saber como eu faço para modificar a próxima div. por exmplo --> no primeiro loop do foreach, mostra a div1, quando acontece o segundo e o terceito loop, quero mostrar a div2  e assim sucessivamente.